# K&F Concept ND2-ND32 Neutral Density Filter for Canon EF 100mm

Tags: canon, canon-ef

I am not quite sure whether this filter:

[K&F Concept ND2-ND32 Neutral Density Filter](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07H9WG54V/ref=pd_luc_rh_sspa_dk_huc_pt_thematic_2?psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExVzJRWlE5T1JIQzFRJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUExMDI3MDA0MUlYN0JRSDg0OFZNOCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNzI2MTAzQTZaUk4zTFRNSjA0JndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfaHVjX3RoZW1hdGljJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==)

will fit this lens:

[Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM](https://www.canon-europe.com/lenses/ef-100mm-f-2-8l-macro-is-usm-lens/)

The thing that I am not quite sure is here in the filter description:

> Note: This filter is made of high-quality aluminium with 52 mm screw
> thread, and only for a lens of 52 mm diameter. Please measure the
> diameter of your camera lens before placing your order.

Diameter of the lens is 67mm, just like this filter diameter. So what about 52mm 'screw thread'?

Comment: I'm not seeing that anywhere in the item description. Did you take it from the "questions" section? The way amazon listings work ALL of the questions for ALL of the multiple products offered in a single listing will show up no matter which one you click on at the top.

Comment: It is in the item description. Check point number 5. (last point)

Comment: "Extremely narrow filter mount prevents vignetting even with a short wide-angle zoom lens - with a front thread for lens caps or lens hoods." is what I see as the last of the five points in the item description.

Comment: Show all, if they are not shown already. This is the last point: Note: This filter is made of high-quality aluminium with 52 mm screw thread, and only for a lens of 52 mm diameter. Please measure the diameter of your camera lens before placing your order.

Comment: That point is only visible if the 52mm version is selected. It is not one of any of the points for the 67mm version. Do you understand that 14 different product sizes are offered on this one page and you must click on the size you want?

Comment: Note: I'm viewing the link above in Google Chrome browser on a desktop PC.. YMMV if you are using a mobile device or a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I've already received an answer (check below).

Comment: @MichaelC When I click the different filter sizes, I see the same descriptive text ("52 mm..." stuff) for all of them. Using Safari on a Mac, it loads Amazon.de in English, and I see what OP describes. When I open the page in Firefox or Chromium, it goes to the German-language version. When I click on the English-language version of the page in Firefox or Chromium, I see what I saw in Safari, what OP quotes.

Comment: @scottbb That's strange, because I'm not seeing the same thing using Chrome on a PC, with either the Deutsch version or the English translation of it. I had a little bit of German language in college (back in the Dark Ages) so I can tell that what is showing before I tell Chrome to translate is the same thing as what I see after it translates the Deutsch to English.

Comment: @MichaelC Are you viewing _Chrome's_ built-in translator to see the English, or Amazon's English version (under the German flag just to the right of the Amazon search box at the top of the page)? Because yeah, my limited German tells me that the German text is nowhere near what the Amazon English copy says.

Comment: I'm (sort of) reading the Deutsch text and then using google to translate it. I assume the OP is in Deutschland and has no need to translate to English? If they are in the U.S., then why not use the US version of amazon? It's not like you can't buy [K&F Concepts](https://www.amazon.com/Concept-Neutral-Variable-Ultra-Slim-Weather-Sealed/dp/B07FQFL2TV) filters from U.S. dealers.

Comment: OK, If I ask amazon to show me the English version on the .de version of amazon, I see it. It's obviously just an oversight for an "alternate" language page that no in Germany thinks will ever be used by someone in Germany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that particular filter at Amazon, it appears K&F Concept probably just provided the exact same "52 mm" descriptive text, regardless of which filter diameter is chosen.

The confusion here isn't a filter or lens thing; it's merely an example of technical issues, misunderstanding at the supplier end, or laziness in providing the correct descriptive text, with regards to e-commerce.

If you order the 67mm filter, it will fit your lens. If you order a 67mm filter but are delivered 52mm, then you were sent the wrong one through no fault of your own, and you should return it to Amazon and complain about the seller's product page.

---

**Update**: This issue might only apply to the English-language version of the filter's page(s) at Amazon.de. [At Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FQFL2TV), the last bullet point's text corresponds correctly with the filter diameter selection choices (37mm / 40.5mm / ... / 52mm / 67mm / ... / etc). Example for the 67mm filter:

> - 【NOTE】This Filter kit is compatible with all 67mm lenses. Please verify your camera's lens thread size(usually marked somewhere on the lens barrel or printed underneath the lens cap) before ordering. The number is always preceded by a "ø" (diameter) symbol.

Answer (score 1):

A 67mm diameter lens will require a 67mm diameter filter **or larger** with a step-up ring or other type of adapter.

A 52mm filter will fit 52mm threads on a lens or another 52mm filter or an adapter with 52mm threads (such as a step-up ring for a smaller diameter lens).

There are step-down adapters as well but they are likely to produce vignetting, so mostly people find step-up rings a better approach.